# Long expressions spanning multiple lines

Tags: vb.net

This is a simple question but it has been giving me a headache. I have a long `if` condition and instead of writing that on one line, I want to write on multiple lines for clarity.

I did some research and managed to find that using `& _` , I can write the expression on the next line. However If I write something like:

```
If Not (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("User").Value Is Nothing) And & _
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("id number").Value Is Nothing) And & _
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("Emailaddress").Value Is Nothing) And & _
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("Date").Value Is Nothing) And & _
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("phone no.").Value Is Nothing) Then

....... 'do something here'
End If
```

The problem is putting `And & _` the system expects a expression. I tried moving the `& _` to other locations such as: before `IS Nothing`, but had no luck.

Can anyone please help me

Comment: What version of VB.NET are you using? Or, since it's probably easier to answer, what version of Visual Studio? You may not need to bother with line continuation characters at all.

Comment: Really, it also works if you remove just `&` or `& _` (VS2012).

Comment: Consider reading [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: removing & works. thank you very much

Comment: & is used for string concatenation, you might saw similar code that concatenated strings on multiple lines.

Comment: for long strings, the `&` would go on the next line, there are gobs of places it is now legal to break expressions to new lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `And &` part is definitely wrong, independent of the line breaks. You could put that whole mess on a single line (remove all of the line breaks) and it still wouldn't compile.

VB.NET uses `And` and `AndAlso` as the names of its bitwise and logical AND operators, respectively. `And` has bitwise semantics, like `&` in C#. `AndAlso` has logical and short-circuiting semantics, like `&&` in C#. You should not (indeed, cannot) use both `And` and `&`. And you *should* be using `AndAlso` here, because you want logical, short-circuiting semantics.

The `_` character at the end of a line serves as a line-continuation character. This is what you saw online, and [this is correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641(v=vs.71).aspx). You can use this to break your expression up into multiple lines.

```
If Not (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("User").Value Is Nothing) AndAlso _
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("id number").Value Is Nothing) AndAlso _
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("Emailaddress").Value Is Nothing) AndAlso _
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("Date").Value Is Nothing) AndAlso _
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("phone no.").Value Is Nothing) Then

....... 'do something here'
End If
```

However, you might not need to do this at all. If you're using a relatively new version of VB.NET, [implicit line continuation has been added to the language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865x40k4.aspx). Any operator (like `And`) will work as an implicit line-continuation operator. So you could just do:

```
If Not (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("User").Value Is Nothing) AndAlso
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("id number").Value Is Nothing) AndAlso
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("Emailaddress").Value Is Nothing) AndAlso
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("Date").Value Is Nothing) AndAlso
       (DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells("phone no.").Value Is Nothing) Then

....... 'do something here'
End If
```

Personally, I would compulsively line up the columns for readability purposes. But I think the VB.NET IDE will fight you on that, so it probably isn't worth it.